# How to Capture Google Analytics User ID & Insert into SQL DataBase for Lead Qualifying

Tags: mysql, google-analytics, google-ads-api

I want to capture Google Analytics User IDs into our company's SQL database WITH the following information: UTM_Source / UTM_Campaign / UTM_Keyword / Goal Completion.

I understand this may require some API work or even a SSIS connection - but my understanding is vague. I know some analytis services may be better equipped but I believe there is a way to hack this.

Thanks!

Comment: Use relevant language API from  https://developers.google.com/analytics/

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)